# How to convert string of digits to List<int> in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to convert this string into List of integers

"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

I tried this, and many others - but all of the convert this string into I think Unicode-integer-representation of digits, e.g. 7 becomes 55 and 1 becomes 49.. what am I doing wrong?
Thank You, for helping.

```
            List<char> source_list = new List<char>();            
            foreach (char x in source)
            {
                source_list.Add(x);
            }
            List<int> new_list = source_list.Select(s => ((int)s)).ToList();
```

Comment: added an answer and explanation why your `((int)s)` is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you want to *cast*, just minus the appropriate *ASCII* character (`'0'`). The assumptions are your `string` is actually just regular *ASCII* numeric characters

```
var result = someString.Select(ch => ch -'0').ToList();
```

Or if you want this faster, you could probably go *pointers* and `unsafe`, it will scale a lot better on larger strings

```
private unsafe static int[] SpeedConvert(string source)
{
   var result = new int[source.Length];
   fixed(int* pResult = result)
      fixed (char* pSource = source)
         for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            *(pResult + i) = *(pSource + i) - '0';
    return result;
}
```

**Benchmark Environemnt**

```
┌──────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│        Test Mode │ Release (64Bit)                            │
│   Test Framework │ .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000) │
╞══════════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Operating System │ Microsoft Windows 10 Pro                   │
│          Version │ 10.0.18362                                 │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│       CPU System │ Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz    │
│  CPU Description │ Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9      │
├──────────────────┼──────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────┤
│  Cores (Threads) │ 4 (8)    │     Architecture │ x64          │
│      Clock Speed │ 3600 MHz │        Bus Speed │ 100 MHz      │
│          L2Cache │ 1 MB     │          L3Cache │ 8 MB         │
└──────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

**Results**

```
┌── Standard input ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Value        │    Average │    Fastest │    Cycles │ Garbage │ Test │        Gain │
├── Scale 2 ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.741 sec ──┤
│ SpeedConvert │   3.548 µs │   1.000 µs │  17.179 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │      0.00 % │
│ Select       │   5.050 µs │   1.800 µs │  22.411 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │    -42.34 % │
├── Scale 20 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.731 sec ──┤
│ SpeedConvert │   3.871 µs │   1.000 µs │  18.084 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │      0.00 % │
│ Select       │   5.555 µs │   2.500 µs │  24.377 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │    -43.50 % │
├── Scale 200 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.754 sec ──┤
│ SpeedConvert │   3.817 µs │   1.100 µs │  18.298 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │      0.00 % │
│ Select       │   9.532 µs │   5.900 µs │  38.478 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │   -149.72 % │
├── Scale 2,000 ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.811 sec ──┤
│ SpeedConvert │   5.148 µs │   1.900 µs │  22.722 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │      0.00 % │
│ Select       │  46.030 µs │  40.300 µs │ 170.014 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │   -794.11 % │
├── Scale 20,000 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 1.509 sec ──┤
│ SpeedConvert │  15.107 µs │  12.400 µs │  58.771 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │      0.00 % │
│ Select       │ 486.696 µs │ 479.300 µs │   1.755 M │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │ -3,121.76 % │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of `static` methods in the `char` class that can help you: `char.IsDigit` and `char.GetNumericValue`.

If you have newline characters (or other non-numeric characters) in the string (which it appears to have since it spans multiple lines), then you will first need to filter out any non-digit characters. You can do this by testing them with `char.IsDigit`.

After that, you can use `char.GetNumericValue` to get the numeric representation of the `char` (as opposed to the ASCII value, which is what you're currently getting).

For example:

```
var result = input.Where(char.IsDigit).Select(char.GetNumericValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Char.GetNumericValue(x) before adding it into source_list where x is any char from your input list

Answer (score 0):

in your example
`source_list.Select(s => ((int)s)).ToList();` you are converting the `char`(ascii) equivalent not the value itself

try this

```
//assume source has no white space
//adding .ToString() to char will convert the char to the real value
var listOfCharConvertedToInt = source.ToCharArray()
                                     .Select(ch => Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString()))
                                     .ToList();
```

Comment: FYI: You don't need `ToCharArray()` because the `string` class already implements `IEnumerable<char>`